# Trying to make my div box and the text inside it not go all over the place when the screen is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am currently trying to make a website. I have done css styling to my code and it works well on a laptop screen device.However I want it to also look nice on the phone as well. How can I make it so my div container box (in which text is in) wont change it's size when the screen is resized? i.e it'll only go downwards not shrink leftwards.

Comment: In order for the community to better help you, please include an example of your code.

Answer (score 2):

when you declare your table or div use % instead of px
to fit the screen.

and use css overflow / wordbreak to make div/table content stay inside of it

Answer (score 0):

at first I advice to use bootstrap for responsible web pages. 
at your way, you have to use % of with, not px, and also you need the hight to make auto, hight: auto; in CSS. and also if you know jquery, you can change the font-size if window resized, or change the width of your div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w < 1280) {
      $('.yourDiv').css('width', '75%');
    } if else (w < 1024) {
      $('.yourDiv').css('width', '100%');
    } else {
      $('.yourDiv').css('width', '50%');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.yourDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="yourDiv">
  <p>Your Text...</p>
</div>
```

you can make like this.

Comment: You can change the width percentages and the font size by using CSS `@media` queries, you don't need any javascript/jquery just to do that.